# Why can't I view my monthly or yearly org agenda?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Issuing `M-x org-agenda-month-vew` and `M-x org-agenda-year-view` yields

`Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil`

Why am I getting this error?

Issuing `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` before the command yields

```
  calendar-gregorian-from-absolute(nil)
  org-agenda-compute-starting-span(nil month nil)
  org-agenda-change-time-span(month nil)
  org-agenda-month-view(nil)
  call-interactively(org-agenda-month-view record nil)
  command-execute(org-agenda-month-view record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "org-agenda-month-view")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
```

Comment: Please include a backtrace by using `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, reproducing the error and adding the backtrace to the question.

Comment: @wasamasa done.

Answer (score 4):

The commands `org-agenda-month-view` and `org-agenda-year-view` are thought to be called from an agenda buffer AFAICS.

If you use the user interface of the agenda to call those functions this constraint is always fullfilled.

If you feel the need for a different behavior for those functions you could try to discuss this topic at the orgmode mailing list.